# Xamarin Classic IOS, Visual Stuidio for mac

Tags: ios, macos, xamarin

Good morning and thank you for your time,

I am maintaining a mobile App made in Xamarin classic IOS with the Visual Studio Mac IDE. Recently Apple told me that I had to increase the SDK of this application to 15 to be able to upload my new version to the App Store, for this I had to update the operating system to MacOS Monterey Version 12.3.1, to later update Xcode 13.4 and to update the SDK of my project, once this change was made in Visual Studio Mac debugging options were disabled and the debug icon was changed to compile. When I access Run in the top menu of visual studio mac, the options to start debugging are disabled and no matter how much I change the debug project options remains the same.

Regards

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Symc.png)

Comment: Could you please try to open Xcode in Mac and then check if it requires installing additional components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very likely that you have some other Debug configuration that works (in Xamarin it could be Debug|iPhone).

Comment: The problem was solved by updating the version of visual studio. Thank you for your response and your time.

Greetings